# Array variable shows wrong command result length when no results

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to execute a command, store the result in an array, and know its size. The problem is that when I assign the command result to an array, it will show size 1 even if the command returned no results.

```
DEVICES=$(some|command)
echo "${#DEVICES[*]}" # Prints 1
```

However, if I do it manually, it works fine:

```
a=0
for i in $(some|command);
do
    a=$((a + 1))
done
echo "$a" # Prints 0
```

How can I assign the result to a variable and have the correct length?

Comment: @EtanReisner You lost the bet :D It returns `[]`.

Comment: Songy deleted answer below was correct, it was my mistake, copied his solution wrong... `DEVICES=( $(some|command) )` works just fine.

Comment: I'll undelete it then ;P Didn't want people doing the wrong thing :P

Comment: @EtanReisner With the quotes, yes. `hexdump -C` returns nothing.

Comment: @Songy Thanks and sorry. I informed the moderators to undelete it too :)

Comment: @m0skit0 No problem :P Was furiously typing into a terminal to figure out what it could be :P

Comment: @EtanReisner It doesn't matter, when you declare a variable then it automatically has an "array length" of 1. Try `var="";echo "${#var[*]}"`

Comment: @User112638726 Huh, interesting. Don't know that I'd noticed that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `DEVICES` an array.

Change `DEVICES=$(some|command)` to `DEVICES=( $(some|command) )`

At the moment it is just a single string

Comment: Note that this both word-splits and expands globs/etc. So this isn't a generally safe pattern to use.